# Mitigate Redshift Locks?

Tags: sql, transactions, amazon-redshift, etl, locks

Hi I am running ETL via Python . 
I have simple sql file that I run from Python like

```
truncate table foo_stg;
insert into foo_stg
(
 select blah,blah .... from tables 
);

truncate table foo;
insert into foo 
(
select * from foo_stg
);
```

This query sometimes takes lock on table which it does not release .
Due to which other processes get queued .

Now I check which table has the lock and kill the process that had caused the lock .

I want to know what changes I can make in my code to mitigate such issues ?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: If the locks are not released you are missing a `commit` somewhere

Comment: I have put a commit statement after each transaction

Comment: Also this happens like in 1 out of 50 times

Comment: You should contact Amazon's support if you are 100% sure you are always committing every transaction.

Comment: Sad Part is that my firm does not have AWS support :(

Answer (score 3):

The `TRUNCATE` is probably breaking your transaction logic. Recommend doing all truncates upfront. I'd also recommend adding some processing logic to ensure that each instance of the ETL process either: A) has exclusive access to the staging tables *or* B) uses a separate set of staging tables.

`TRUNCATE` in Redshift (and many other DBs) does an implicit `COMMIT`.

> […be aware that TRUNCATE commits the transaction in which it is run.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRUNCATE.html)

Redshift tries to makes this clear by returning the following INFO message to confirm success: `TRUNCATE TABLE and COMMIT TRANSACTION`. However, this INFO message may not be displayed by the SQL client tool. Run the SQL in `psql` to see it.

Comment: This is a huge difference to Postgres, where `truncate` does not do an implicit commit.

Comment: So I do have a staging table here foo_stg is a staging table and foo is the final table used in reporting so all operations are taking place in staging table and the data is moved to the final table in the last insert operation

Comment: Not sure how this help should I replace the truncate statement by anything else ?

Comment: You can't use truncate inside a transaction. So you can either: A) run the `TRUNCATE` statements first and then do the rest of the work inside your transaction or B) use a `DELETE FROM staging_table;` inside your transaction in place of truncate. If you choose option B then you need to run `VACUUM DELETE ONLY staging_table;` after you commit the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I created a table the first time and tried to load it from the stage table using insert into a table from select c1,c2,c3 from stage;I am running this using python script.
The table is locking and not loading the data. Another interesting scenario is when I run the same insert SQL from the editor, it is loading, and after that my python script loads the same table without any locks. But the first time only the table lock is happening. Not sure what is the issue.